# CSS: applying border to tab focus image

Tags: html, css, navigation

Using CSS, how do I put a border around a  focused using keyboard TAB to navigate through the page?

Here is shown how to do it with text but not with images

http://www.joepettersson.com/demo/the-outline-property

```
* { outline: none;}
```

I tried:

```
a img:focus{
    border: 5px solid #900;
}
```

but won't work.

Comment: The page cited shows some ways to modify the *outline* (not border), and the rule quoted just removes the default outline. It is unclear whether you want outline or border. (Generally, outline is better.)

Comment: Generally resetting the outline-property to none for all elements is a really bad thing. There is no good reason why one should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
a:focus img {
    border: 5px solid #900;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/upecoy/1/edit)

```
a:focus {
    border: 5px solid #990000;
}
```