# :focus not working on images during tab navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The HTML:

```
<div id="banner" class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <a href="http://www.zhaw.ch/de/zhaw.html">
    <img class="img-responsive" id="zhaw_logo" src="fileadmin/media/images/zhaw_logo_de.gif" alt="ZHAW Homepage" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.engineering.zhaw.ch/de.html">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="fileadmin/media/images/InIT_header.png" alt="School of Engineering Homepage" />
  </a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
a .img-responsive:hover, a .img-responsive:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
  /* IE6-9 */

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

When I hover over the images, I get the blue shadowy outline that I want. However, if I try to use the Tab Key to navigate through the webpage, the links in the images are selected (I can see that in firefox) but I don't get the blue outline box around it. Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Do the answer to the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916574/css-applying-border-to-tab-focus-image help?

Comment: _“Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly here?”_ – you’re expecting the focus to be on the image, but it is on the link instead. `a:focus .img-responsive` should work.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. That does solve my question and tell me what I was doing wrong. However, this does not work on Safari. I am looking into it, but if someone knows, please do tell me.

Comment: Thanks @Marlun. Should have used searched better.

Answer (score 2):

change this to `a .img-responsive:hover, a .img-responsive:focus {` to

```
a:hover .img-responsive, a:focus .img-responsive {
 ....
}
```

tab going to the `a` tag not the image!

Comment: oops i see the comment from @CBroe same thing

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Doesn't work on Safari though, I am looking into it. If you know, please tell me.

Comment: it works in safari mac for me. you just didnt set a border width in your css!